# Forward svn port

Tags: svn, port-forwarding

We have our svn server on a machine not accessible from the internet. But we need to be able to check out code from the internet over ssh. Given that we can do port forwarding on a machine accessible from the internet, whats the best way to set this up?

```
Internet -> A machine on our network - > svn server

            (Port forward here? )
```

If not port forwarding, whats the most secure way of doing this, if there is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
ssh -L3980:svnserver:3980 me@insidemachine
```

This would let you do svn operations to `svn://localhost`; and your working copy would point to that.  You could change that by using `svn switch --relocate`, but it's going to get a bit cumbersome.  You could do that same ssh from within the firewall to avoid the switch, but that too may be awkward.

If you can setup a VPN, I think you'll find that to be much more convenient, particularly if there is also a bugtracker or something on your internal network.

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming the machine with the SVN server has a connection to the network and can browse the internet. You just don't have and don't want to open up a port on the actual server. Correct?

In that case:

I would use VPN to get onto the network you should then be able to update your local SVN files to their newest revisions so you can view/work on them. Once finished you can commit your changes back to the server. For this you will need to setup VPN and forward the ports on the router to the VPN server.

OR

you could RDP to a workstation that has the files on them. Its a little less secure though. Then view/work on the files off the RDP machine.You will need to forward port 3389 or another port if you use a non standard RDP port which will increase security.